# Titles Printing Multiple Times?

Tags: python

So, I'm currently a student in an intro to computer science course, and for my final I'm working with a text file of books with information attached.

I have a function which asks for a start year, and an end year. The function will then print out all of the books within the year range given by the user.

The problem I'm having is that the same book is being printed multiple times.

```
def display_books_year_range():
    start_year = input("Enter your start year :\n")
    end_year = input("Enter your end year: \n")
    book_counter = 0
    for book in years:
        if start_year <= book <= end_year:
                book_index = years.index(book)
                print(titles[book_index] + ", by:", authors[book_index])
                book_counter = book_counter + 1
    if book_counter == 0:
        print("No books have been found within that range.\n")
        make_choice()
```

So far I've tried creating a list, and if the requirements are met and the book isn't already in the list, it will add the book. But even with that, I'm still getting multiples.

I've also tried using the range function as well, but I get the same result.

I have a feeling the problem is with the for loop, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Edit: Here's a section of an example output (it's very long so I don't wanna put the whole thing). For the input, the beginning year is 1950, and the end year is 1980.

Curtain, by: Agatha Christie
Curtain, by: Agatha Christie
QB VII, by: Leon Uris
Love Is Eternal, by: Irving Stone
A Shade of Difference, by: Allen Drury
QB VII, by: Leon Uris
Firestarter, by: Stephen King
Across the River and Into the Trees, by: Ernest Hemingway
Firestarter, by: Stephen King
By Love Possessed, by: James Gould Cozzens
Firestarter, by: Stephen King
1876, by: Gore Vidal
Breakfast of Champions, by: Kurt Vonnegut
Andersonville, by: McKinley Kantor
QB VII, by: Leon Uris
The Arrangement, by: Elia Kazan

Comment: Write your if condition using AND, OR

Comment: @starboy_jb That isn't the problem.  Python supports chained comparisons.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding "the same book being printed multiple times"? Perhaps an example output?

Comment: Please follow advice above for example output (and input if possible) to make it easier to answer your question. In the meantime, if the books don't have unique years, this will print the first book appearing for that year n times (where n is number of books having that year). `list.index(value)` will return the first match.

Comment: @S-c-r-a-t-c-h-y Please note that begging for upvotes/accept votes is seriously frowned upon here. Note also that comments should only be used for clarifying questions and answers.

Comment: I'm not begging I posted an answer and he thanked me but didn't upvote like he should have but now this is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
def display_books_year_range():
    start_year = int(input("Enter your start year :\n"))
    end_year = int(input("Enter your end year: \n"))
    book_counter = 0
    for book, title, author in zip(years, titles, authors):
        if start_year <= book <= end_year:
                print(f'{title}, by: {author}')
                book_counter = book_counter + 1
    if book_counter == 0:
        print("No books have been found within that range.\n")
        make_choice()
```

By using the zip function, you can loop over every elements of multiples list at the same time and you don't run into the issue of the list.index() method.

Comment: FYI, the line that sets `book_index` is now unnecessary and can be deleted.

Comment: yes I edited my code and removed it thanks for letting me notice

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is `index`.  Remember that returns you the FIRST match.  If you have four books from 2005, then you'll see that first book four times.

```
def display_books_year_range():
    start_year = input("Enter your start year :\n")
    end_year = input("Enter your end year: \n")
    book_counter = 0
    for year,title,author in zip(years,titles,authors):
        if start_year <= year <= end_year:
            print(title + ", by:", author)
            book_counter = book_counter + 1
    if book_counter == 0:
        print("No books have been found within that range.\n")
        make_choice()
```

In the long run, you shouldn't be storing that info in three separate lists.  Instead, create a "class Book" to store your three pieces of information.  Then you can iterate through your list of books as a unit.